# Verónica (2017 Spanish film) ending explanation

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, veronica

In the movie [Verónica (2017 Spanish film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ver%C3%B3nica_(2017_Spanish_film)) there can be different explanations,

1. She was crazy and imagined things.
2. She was possessed by a ghost.
3. She was not possessed and there was another ghost.

Only Veronica sees and hears the ghost and things like that. At the end she remembers things like *moving the glass in the Ouija board by herself, choking her sister, and closing door by herself*.

So how should the movie be interpreted, especially the ending scenes ?

Answer (score 4):

Lots of ghost movies go like this: the only people that see the ghost die, so no one else can be sure of what happened (like the [Nightmare on Elm Street](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087800/) franchise).

The story is supposedly inspired by real events in the [Valleca's case](http://www.ghosttheory.com/2016/02/08/a-strange-death-in-vallecas-madrid).

So I'd say this one is open to your own interpretation.